# How can I move existing npm package to a new organisation?

Tags: npm

I created a npm organisation `org`, How can I move existing `<org>-<xxx>` packages into my org.

Comment: Can you re-publish the package in your org? If that's not a solution, can you explain why not? Are you hoping for a transparent redirect when people do `npm install` or something like that?

Comment: According to [this Github Issue comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7515#issuecomment-76746663) the way to go is re-publishing unless you've got a really larger number of packages, where npm-support might help.